# White space under the navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

When `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO`, a white space occur under the navigation bar, like this:

[image: Sample screenshot]

How can I remove it?

```
// From above example
(void)loadUI
{
    [self.countriesButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(243/255.0) green:(178/255.0) blue:(128/255.0) alpha:1]];
    [self.countriesButton.layer setCornerRadius:10];
    [self.countriesButton setClipsToBounds:YES];

    /// set attributes for Navigation Bar
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Welcome"; // Title of Navigation Bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(243/255.0) green:(178/255.0) blue:(128/255.0) alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Comment: are you using a scrollview or table view in this viewcontroller ?

Comment: Where do you set your view frame ? In a xib file, in the code ?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 8):

Im gonna chime in how i solved this one since it was easy and worked well.

In your storyboard select the view controller that is getting the whitespace under the opaque navbar.

Then go to 'Attributes Inspector' -> 'View Controller' -> 'Extend Edges' -> **Check the box that says 'Under Opaque Bars'**

Comment: This solves the problem for me but do I have to do it for all the views?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

This is introduced in iOS7 and app will crash if you don't check system version before calling.
You can also set this from storyboard '**Adjust Scroll View Insets**'

[image]

Comment: What did you select in IB to get Navigation Controller options? I don't see these when I select the top view with my xib open in IB.

Comment: In Document Outline (left sidebar on IB) select root node of your controller, not view within it. Or zoom-out and click on controller inside storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Comment: My bad, I think I mis-clicked when voting delete.  I supported the vote because the answer is non-authoritative, and based on feedback it seems that the answer was not tested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when you switch between translucent and opaque. I don't really know why, but the view is automatically resized. It is the same when you switch from opaque to translucent, the view expands at the top.

My guess is that you are probably setting somewhere else the bar as translucent. In the xib file or previously in the code.

Answer (score -1):

try adding a 0 px image as shadow of navbar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```